# Simple divs in CSS "not working" when text in them?

Tags: css, html

I have a big div with 3 small divs in it. You can look at it here: http://jsfiddle.net/V9tFM/

I have one major problem: When the smaller div has some text in itself, it gets out of the big div. Like here:

What is the problem and how could I solve it?

[Tested in Chrome 16 and FireFox 3.5]

[image]

Comment: thanks for adding a link to the jsFiddle example to make debugging easier!

Comment: @asawilliams yeah, more people need to do that when asking questions on here. I always do. (given that I'm working with HTML/CSS/javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to the .tour_bit class

Comment: Oh thanks so much... Forgot to add that in the beginning. Will accept your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you used relative positioning for the small div's. You should use absolute positioning so they are taken out of the flow of DOM elements and can go wherever you want them.

What I did to fix this was I used absolute positioning to place them relative to the larger div.

Here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/V9tFM/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is a solution as well... but not quite what I am looking for. Anyway +1 :)